# React Native Image Background

Tags: react-native

I am trying to do this by using the green background like an image, but I need to do it via styling. Can someone guide me on how to do this without using the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Not sure if there is a solid way to do that just with RN styles. 
I was thinking that we can use these [CSS tricks](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)
so I tried them [here](https://snack.expo.dev/s8KC6snE-) but it's not working on Android. If I want to do that, I would use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) as you are free to draw whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make it's position absolute, make the zIndex high, and then take use of transform (https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms) to rotate it the way you want.

Super short example of using these things,

```
<View style{{position:"absolute",top:0,bottom:0,left:0,
            right:0,zIndex:10,
            backGroundColor:"green",
            transform: [{ rotate: "45deg" }]]
           }}>

</View>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me learn a new concept